# In Google Analytics, how do I plot on a timeline users who visited one page but not another?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm looking for some help creating a Google Analytics report that shows, in a timeline, the number of Users who visited one page (e.g. Checkout page) but **NOT** another page (e.g. Thank You page), and in that order. This seems like such a simply report to run, but I cannot seem to find the right settings in Google Analytics to pull this together.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a segment with the following settings:

- Include sessions
- Page includes /checkout (replace with your checkout URL) AND
- Page excludes /thankyou (replace with whatever your thank you page URL is)